# My Menu in Wordpress line breaks for no reason.

Tags: wordpress, css

So my menu in WordPress on http://nectarcantina.com is suddenly not working.

The last menu item always line breaks, regardless of if there are 6 menu items or only 3.

I've been digging through the CSS and can't find anything to do with a last-child.

[image: Mneu is Line Breaking]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this

```
.edgtf-vertical-align-containers .edgtf-position-right {
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: This worked, but I had to set it at 60% so the entire menu didn't line break. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Remove `float: right;` from `.edgtf-position-right`

Comment: This also worked, I'm not sure which one is technically the correct way to do it, but both answers worked, thank you @Bojan259